# I'm getting a "Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'ShapeStyle'" and "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression;...."

Tags: swiftui

I'm getting a Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'ShapeStyle' on the NavigationStack line.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    /// View Properties
    @State private var showSignup: Bool = false
    /// Keyboard Status
    @State private var isKeyboardShowing: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Login(showSignup: $showSignup)
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showSignup) {
                    SignUp(showSignup: $showSignup)
                }
                /// Checking if any Keyboard is Visible
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification), perform: { _ in
                    /// Disabling it for signup view
                    if !showSignup {
                        isKeyboardShowing = true
                    }
                })
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification), perform: { _ in
                    isKeyboardShowing = false
                })
        }
        .overlay {
            /// iOS 17 Bounce Animations
            if #available(iOS 17, *) {
                /// Since this Project Supports iOS 16 too.
                CircleView()
                    .animation(.smooth(duration: 0.45, extraBounce: 0), value: showSignup)
                    .animation(.smooth(duration: 0.45, extraBounce: 0), value: isKeyboardShowing)
            } else {
                CircleView()
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3), value: showSignup)
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3), value: isKeyboardShowing)
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// Moving Blurred background
    @ViewBuilder
    func CircleView() -> some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(.linearGradient(colors: [.yellow, .orange, .red], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            /// Moving When the Signup Pages Loads/Dismisses
            .offset(x: showSignup ? 90 : -90, y: -90 - (isKeyboardShowing ? 200 : 0))
            .blur(radius: 15)
            .hSpacing(showSignup ? .trailing : .leading)
            .vSpacing(.top)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Additionally, I am getting "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project" for the below block. I'm getting the same error in 3 other files for the same line of code "var body: some View." Im pasting one of the blocks below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Login: View {
    @Binding var showSignup: Bool
    /// View Properties
    @State private var emailID: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @State private var showForgotPasswordView: Bool = false
    /// Reset Password View (with New Password and Confimration Password View)
    @State private var showResetView: Bool = false
    /// Optional, Present If you want to ask OTP for login
    @State private var askOTP: Bool = false
    @State private var otpText: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15, content: {
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            
            Text("Login")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
            
            Text("Please sign in to continue")
                .font(.callout)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                .padding(.top, -5)
            
            VStack(spacing: 25) {
                /// Custom Text Fields
                CustomTF(sfIcon: "at", hint: "Email ID", value: $emailID)
                
                CustomTF(sfIcon: "lock", hint: "Password", isPassword: true, value: $password)
                    .padding(.top, 5)
                
                Button("Forgot Password?") {
                    showForgotPasswordView.toggle()
                }
                .font(.callout)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .tint(.appYellow)
                .hSpacing(.trailing)
                
                /// Login Button
                GradientButton(title: "Login", icon: "arrow.right") {
                    /// YOUR CODE
                    askOTP.toggle()
                }
                .hSpacing(.trailing)
                /// Disabling Until the Data is Entered
                .disableWithOpacity(emailID.isEmpty || password.isEmpty)
            }
            .padding(.top, 20)
            
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            
            HStack(spacing: 6) {
                Text("Don't have an account?")
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                
                Button("SignUp") {
                    showSignup.toggle()
                }
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .tint(.appYellow)
            }
            .font(.callout)
            .hSpacing()
        })
        .padding(.vertical, 15)
        .padding(.horizontal, 25)
        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
        /// Asking Email ID For Sending Reset Link
        .sheet(isPresented: $showForgotPasswordView, content: {
            if #available(iOS 16.4, *) {
                /// Since I wanted a Custom Sheet Corner Radius
                ForgotPassword(showResetView: $showResetView)
                    .presentationDetents([.height(300)])
//                    .presentationCornerRadius(30)
            } else {
                ForgotPassword(showResetView: $showResetView)
                    .presentationDetents([.height(300)])
            }
        })
        /// Resetting New Password
        .sheet(isPresented: $showResetView, content: {
            if #available(iOS 16.4, *) {
                /// Since I wanted a Custom Sheet Corner Radius
                PasswordResetView()
                    .presentationDetents([.height(350)])
//                    .presentationCornerRadius(30)
            } else {
                PasswordResetView()
                    .presentationDetents([.height(350)])
            }
        })
        /// OTP Prompt
        .sheet(isPresented: $askOTP, onDismiss: {
            /// YOUR CODE
            /// Reset OTP if You Want
            // otpText = ""
        }, content: {
            if #available(iOS 16.4, *) {
                /// Since I wanted a Custom Sheet Corner Radius
                OTPView(otpText: $otpText)
                    .presentationDetents([.height(350)])
//                    .presentationCornerRadius(30)
            } else {
                OTPView(otpText: $otpText)
                    .presentationDetents([.height(350)])
            }
        })
    }
}
```

These are the other two views.

```
import SwiftUI

struct OTPVerificationView: View {
    /// - View Properties
    @Binding var otpText: String
    /// - Keyboard State
    @FocusState private var isKeyboardShowing: Bool
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0){
            /// - OTP Text Boxes
            /// Change Count Based on your OTP Text Size
            ForEach(0..<6,id: \.self){index in
                OTPTextBox(index)
            }
        }
        .background(content: {
            TextField("", text: $otpText.limit(6))
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
                /// - Hiding it Out
                .frame(width: 1, height: 1)
                .opacity(0.001)
                .blendMode(.screen)
                .focused($isKeyboardShowing)
        })
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        /// - Opening Keyboard When Tapped
        .onTapGesture {
            isKeyboardShowing = true
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                Button("Done"){
                    isKeyboardShowing = false
                }
                .tint(.appYellow)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .hSpacing(.trailing)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: OTP Text Box
    @ViewBuilder
    func OTPTextBox(_ index: Int)->some View{
        ZStack{
            if otpText.count > index{
                /// - Finding Char At Index
                let startIndex = otpText.startIndex
                let charIndex = otpText.index(startIndex, offsetBy: index)
                let charToString = String(otpText[charIndex])
                Text(charToString)
            }else{
                Text(" ")
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
        .background {
            /// - Highlighting Current Active Box
            let status = (isKeyboardShowing && otpText.count == index)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6, style: .continuous)
                .stroke(status ? .appYellow : Color.gray,lineWidth: status ? 3 : 0.5)
                /// - Adding Animation
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2), value: isKeyboardShowing)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}

// MARK: Binding <String> Extension
extension Binding where Value == String{
    func limit(_ length: Int)->Self{
        if self.wrappedValue.count > length{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.wrappedValue = String(self.wrappedValue.prefix(length))
            }
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

Here's the last one.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SignUp: View {
    @Binding var showSignup: Bool
    /// View Properties
    @State private var emailID: String = ""
    @State private var fullName: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    /// Optional, Present If you want to ask OTP for Signup
    @State private var askOTP: Bool = false
    @State private var otpText: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15, content: {
            /// Back Button
            Button(action: {
                showSignup = false
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
            })
            .padding(.top, 10)
            
            Text("SignUp")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .padding(.top, 25)
            
            Text("Please sign up to continue")
                .font(.callout)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                .padding(.top, -5)
            
            VStack(spacing: 25) {
                /// Custom Text Fields
                CustomTF(sfIcon: "at", hint: "Email ID", value: $emailID)
                
                CustomTF(sfIcon: "person", hint: "Full Name", value: $fullName)
                    .padding(.top, 5)
                
                CustomTF(sfIcon: "lock", hint: "Password", isPassword: true, value: $password)
                    .padding(.top, 5)
                
                Text("By signing up, you're agreeing to our **[Terms & Condition](https://apple.com)** and **[Privacy Policy](https://apple.com)**")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .tint(.appYellow)
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                
                /// SignUp Button
                GradientButton(title: "Continue", icon: "arrow.right") {
                    /// YOUR CODE
                    askOTP.toggle()
                }
                .hSpacing(.trailing)
                /// Disabling Until the Data is Entered
                .disableWithOpacity(emailID.isEmpty || password.isEmpty || fullName.isEmpty)
            }
            .padding(.top, 20)
            
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            
            HStack(spacing: 6) {
                Text("Already have an account?")
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                
                Button("Login") {
                    showSignup = false
                }
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .tint(.appYellow)
            }
            .font(.callout)
            .hSpacing()
        })
        .padding(.vertical, 15)
        .padding(.horizontal, 25)
        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
        /// OTP Prompt
        .sheet(isPresented: $askOTP, onDismiss: {
            /// YOUR CODE
            /// Reset OTP if You Want
            // otpText = ""
        }, content: {
            if #available(iOS 16.4, *) {
                /// Since I wanted a Custom Sheet Corner Radius
                OTPView(otpText: $otpText)
                    .presentationDetents([.height(350)])
//                  .presentationCornerRadius(30)
            } else {
                OTPView(otpText: $otpText)
                    .presentationDetents([.height(350)])
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I tried using code I found from a Patreon page and it's not behaving as expected. The errors are baffling. I've tried everything.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. The code you posted isn't minimal *at all*.

Comment: So you have four compilation errors you need to sort out. An often successful strategy for these kind of errors and specially the second one is to comment out code in your view piece by piece until you have identified the incorrect code, once that is done and you only compile that code you most often gets a much more informative error message from the compiler or you have spotted the issue yourself. Tedious work for sure but you got to do it yourself.

Comment: My ChapGPT account gave me the same advice :/ Regardless, I think you are correct.